# Commerce 2 Twig and Retail Price

Tags: commerce

I have a use case that I need to add the retail price on a receipt twig next to the discounted unit price. Ive tried every possible field syntax I could think to try, looked everywhere and stumped...

{{ order_items.i_need_the_retail_price... }}

Is it possible to get that related field with twig syntax? It doesnt appear to be carried into Order Items.

Comment: Did you try dumping the variable?

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: Ill give it a shot thank you.

Comment: Using dump on the totals key gives me this data in an array: price (with the discount), percentage off, amount off etc all based on the entire line item though.

The order_entity key hangs on a dump, can I drill down inside that dump somehow?

Comment: Maybe just tell it to print 1-20 then I can try 21-40 etc? Im looking thru docs...

Comment: You can inspect all the available variables inside the twig file and then use your logic to combine the numbers to get the result. Can't you?

Comment: I cant seem to get a list of Order Item or Order Entity available fields using dump. Im relatively new to this. I was reading this was by design because pricing can change, products are discontinued etc but the order shouldn't change.

The available relevant fields in Order_Items totals that Im finding are discount (.365), discounted unit price and line item total. Just doing math, larger quantities could make a price round the wrong the wrong way and this wouldnt be valid for different currencies would it?

Comment: Where are you looking to get this themed? Which part of the buying process?

Comment: This is the documentation on Receipt emails - https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/customize-order-receipt-emails

Comment: As part of a line item in the email receipt twig. 

Im not sure how to find out what fields are available in order_entity, and what syntax to use to pull the orig unit price if its there.

Comment: {{ dump(_context|order_entity) }} this gives me a white screen, and other versions of it I may be doing that all wrong...

Comment: You will only be able to dump variables that are available in the context.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours learning twig filters I can calculate the retail price in each line item with this:

```
{% for adjustment in totals.adjustments %}
{% set disc_percent_remainder = 1 - adjustment.percentage %}
{% set disc_unit_price_raw_2 = order_item.getUnitPrice|commerce_price_format %}
{% set disc_unit_price_raw_1 = disc_unit_price_raw_2|trim(' USD', 'right') %}
{% set disc_unit_price_raw = disc_unit_price_raw_1|trim('$', 'left') %}
{% set disc_unit_price = (disc_unit_price_raw * 100) / disc_percent_remainder %}
${{ (disc_unit_price / 100)|round(2, 'ceil') }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is a horrible work-around I'm sure, ruins any chance of multiple currencies and Im sure can be cleaned up a lot with nesting some of this. But, it comes up with the correct retail pice.